# regular expression to remove unwanted html tags in <description> tag of rss feed

Tags: iphone, xml, regex, rss, nsregularexpression

I am getting RSS feeds from different sources. There are dozen different types of RSS output I am receiving. I am using an XML parser to parse/get the `<item>`, `<title>`, `<link>`, `<description>` tags.

After getting the description value of each item, I am using regular expression to parse the description field to get image link(if any) and clear text. The following regular expression works for Yahoo/CNN feeds.

```
@"<p><a.+?><img src=\"(.+?)\".+?<\\/a>(.+?)<\\/p>" ;
```

But still there are some unwanted characters leaving behind in the description(the second match in above regex).

Here I am looking for some suggestions, on, how to put in different regex to evaluate the RSS description and get "clear text" & "image links". Again, putting lot of regular expressions and comparing each ones success resulting in performance loss.

To summarize, there are two problems, I am seeing here.

1. Construct different regex, apply each one against description field, check the success and take output.(applying 4 or 5 regex, performance loss will be there) In this step I am trying to separate description & image link.
2. The description got above, is still not a clear text, needs to remove lot of other extra characters and tags. I need a regular expression here, to remove all of those extra unnecessary things. Somebody who have already done this, can help me in this regard.

Comment: the regular expression,i have added, has been changed. what tags should i add to show correctly here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Amber, the link you have shown, looks like, it itself is a complete book on this topic

Answer (score 0):

you can put all the unwanted characters in a set and clear the string you want from it .. check this function

```
- (NSString *) stripTags:(NSString *)str{
NSString *clearString;
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant;

doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-=+[]{}:/?.><;,!@#$%^&*\n()\r'"];

clearString = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];

return clearString;}
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: this will just help me in removing the tags, but not the entire tags and their inline content.

Comment: this will remove any of special character in the set from the string you pass it to the function .. i used it , its do the job :)

Comment: i am talking about the entire tags and their inline text, not the individual characters.